Induced flat metric from holomorphic quadratic differential
Given a holomorphic quadratic differential $q$ on a Riemann surface, there is a natural coordinate to make $q=z^kdz\otimes dz$ locally.
On A Primer on Mapping Class Groups, p.312, it says, "The natural coordinates for a holomorphic quadratic differential $q$ on a Riemann surface $X$ endow $X$ with a singular Euclidean (flat) metric".
On these notes, p.143, the associated Riemann metric is given by $|\rho(z)|(dx^2+dy^2)$ when the holomorphic quadratic differential $q$ is (locally) given by $\rho(z)dz^2$. And it's flat since $\rho(z)$ is holomorphic.
My question is, why do we need the natural coordinates to endow $X$ with a singular Euclidean (flat) metric? It seems that, even without the natural coordinates, we have the (flat) Riemann metric $|\rho(z)|(dx^2+dy^2)$.

The issue is not that the metric is flat; as you say it is of course flat.
The issue is what kind of coordinate change exhibits that flatness: near any point where the quadratic form does not have a zero there exists a holomorphic change of coordinates which puts the quadratic differential into the form $dz^2$ (where the metric is $dx^2+dy^2$), and that change of cooordinates is unique up to transformations of the form $\pm z + c$ (for some complex $c$).
